# problem in deleting record

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I have a entity manager em1 .em1 starts a transcation tx on db1 table1.Now inside tx  i call a API getdata().This API creastes a new entitymanger em2 and return 1 record.Now if entity manger em1 tries to delete the record returned by em1 , it hangs.Code times out.Is the record locked by em1.How can ii solve this problem?

```
create em1
//em1 start transcation tx1
tx1.start
Object r = getData();
em1 tried to delete r //code hangs here
tx1.commit


Object getData(){
create em2
return data found using em2
}
```

Comment: Is this OpenJPA or Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create an em2. Pass the em1 as a parameter to `getData()` method. Doing so, you're operating only one em1.

I don't know exactly, but it seems that em1 is putting lock on the related table, so you can't do anything outside.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether EM2's record have anything to do with the tables involved in EM1. If so, then it may be because EM2 wasn't closed. Note that even "select" events involves transactions. So, I would say that the first thing would be to add explicit transactions demarcation in EM2. Implicit transactions are not really a good thing, and depending on the database and isolation levels you are using, the underlying database may be waiting for the EM2's implicit transaction to finish, causing a dead lock in your code.

My suggestion:

```
Object getData(){
  create em2
  tx2.start
  get record 
  tx2.commit
  close em2
  return record
}
```

As a good practice, try to always explicitly begin and commit a transaction, even for reading purposes. Remember that even if you don't specify a transaction, your database *will* start one implicitly.